# How do I capture standard input if it exists, without waiting for it?

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments, stdin

I have a C# command line application.  I need to capture standard input *if it's provided*.  If not, execution should just begin.

I've played around with all sorts of combinations of:

```
Console.OpenStandardInput()
Console.ReadLine()
Console.In.Peek()
```

All of them block, waiting for input.  This is not what I want.  Standard input should be optional.  If it's not provided, the program should start without it and without waiting for it.

Comment: I'm only guessing here, but it seems like you are confusing the standard input for command line arguments.  Command line arguments are provided to the app as it starts; standard input is input entered in *after* the app is already running.  I doubt you are expecting people to type your program name, press enter, then start typing instantly; and even were that the case, users couldn't type fast enough to pre-empt the program startup....

Comment: No, I want both.  I have a bunch of command line arguments, but I also want people to be able to (1) pipe data to it, or (2) direct file contents to it.  Like:  `echo foo | myexe.exe` or `myexe.exe < myfile.txt`

Comment: then why not use a simple while loop like `while ((s = Console.ReadLine()) != null)`?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Standard input will always exist in a console app. But it may be redirected to a file or otherwise the terminal.

Comment: Okay, if someone calls my program like this `myexe.exe < myfile.txt` or `echo foo | myexe.exe` -- how do I get the contents of "myfile.txt" or the string "foo", respectively?

Comment: Side note "capture" usually used in context of reading/writing output of another program... "Read" may be better. Also inlining comment about redirect to the post would likely make your post much easier to recognize by future visitors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I found it. This is apparently new in .NET 4.5

```
if (Console.IsInputRedirected)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput(), Console.InputEncoding))
    {
       _stdin = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```